# Delphi XE8 Поддержка русского языка

Tags: delphi

Недавно поставил новый delphi, столкнулся с неприятной проблемой, программа нормально работает с русским языком, но превращает в каракули в listbox'е, как исправить?

Comment: что вы используете? VCL или FM. Но XE8 использует Utf-8. Так что не должно быть проблем.

Comment: И кстати, как вы передаете текст в ListBox ?

Comment: Нет, я забиваю текст в проге напрямую в item's, и тогда начинается аброкадабра, но когда открываю правку в новой форме там отображается нормальный русский текст.

Comment: Какой `charset` стоит у шрифта этого listbox'а?

Comment: Как это посмотреть, ибо в delpi я не особо хорошо разобрался, пока.

Comment: О, спасибо, все заработало!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выберите в дизайнере свой листбокс, потом в инспекторе объектов найдите свойство `Font` разверните его и там увидите `Charset`. Правильное значение `DEFAULT_CHARSET`. И убедитесь что выбранный шрифт поддерживает юникод. Попробуйте поставить какой-нибудь стандартный шрифт: Arial, Times, Tahoma. Если вы в новом проекте нигде не меняли настройки шрифтов, то все должно работать "из коробки".

---

PS: Раньше у комментария была кнопка "преобразовать в ответ" или мне приснилось?

Comment: Прошу прощения, на радостях забыл пометить.